# How to add "js file" in checkout page in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i am trying to add a custom js file in prestashop but i have no idea about it.

Any thoughts how to add js file in prestashop ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to edit this file `themes/your_theme/templates/_partials/javascript.tpl` and use this code:

```
{if $page.page_name == 'checkout'}
<script src="{$urls.js_url}your_file.js">
{/if}
```

`{$urls.js_url}` == `http://domain.test/themes/your_theme/assets/js/`